# Storyboards: A loop of Modal Segues?

Tags: xcode, ios5, interface-builder, storyboard, uistoryboard

I want to implement something using Storyboards, but I don't know the best way to accomplish it.
I don't want to use a Navigation Controller, since I don't want the navigation bar at the top.
I just want the ability to switch from one view controller to the next.

I have a **Main Menu** view controller, which will segue into other views, and those views might segue to other views... Now, lets say that the last view in the chain has a "Return To Menu" button: should I just segue from that *button* to the Menu view controller? Or should I somehow dismiss all of the previous view controllers?

I don't need iOS to hold a copy of the Main Menu view controller after the user taps out of it, but I can't seem to find a way to just load a new view controller and present it, instead of having a parent view display it "modally".

- Would it cause a memory leak if I just create a loop of modal segues?

(for example: *Main Menu --> VC1 --> VC2 --> Main Menu --> VC3 --> VC4 --> Main Menu...*)

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each segue creates a new instance of the destination view controller, so having a segue back to the main menu is not a good idea.

You would be better off dismissing the presented view controller(s), but note that it is possible to use a navigation controller without showing the navigation bar - the navigation controller has a property, `navigationBarHidden`, which you can set to hide this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It was helpful. And I believe I can change the default push/pop animation of a Nav Controller, so that might do the trick. I'll just need to look up on Google a way to jump to a specific view in the stack of a Nav Controller :) Thanks!